# Firebase & Backbone: Application Authentication

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, session-cookies, firebase

Currently I'm building an application using firebase and backbone.marionette and I'm trying to implement secure sessions. Previously, I was able to simply bypass the login page by typing in a specific route in the URL bar, but to fix this I added an initializer to the app to check if a user is logged in or not, like so:

```
    @addInitializer((options) =>
        # Instantiate firebase
        @firebase = new Firebase("https://*******.firebaseIO.com/")

        @authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient @firebase, 
            (error, user) =>
                if (error)
                    console.log(error)
                else if (user)
                    console.log('User ID: ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider)
                    @logged = true
                    @trigger('logged_in')
                    @router.navigate('home', {trigger: true})
                else
                    @logged = false
                    @trigger('logged_out')
                    @router.navigate('login', {trigger: true})

     )
```

And now before I render a page in `routes.coffee` I check if `@logged` is true or not.

But I feel like this is sketchy security at best. Couldn't someone just fire up the console and set the flag to `true` themselves?

Does anyone know the proper way to do sessions with backbone and firebase?

Answer (score 1):

There's fundamentally no way to guarantee security on the client side. A smart hacker can always get around any restrictions you place on the GUI (such as setting @logged to true).

Instead, you need to set up security rules on the Firebase side so that non-authenticated users can't change data they're not supposed. This way, even if a hacker messes with your GUI they can't actually access or change anything they're not supposed to.

There's an overview of Firebase auth and security rules here:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/security-quickstart.html